# Extending uniform convergence of analytic functions on larger domains

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence, holomorphic-functions, analytic-functions, absolute-convergence

Let $f_k, f: ]-\infty , 1 [ \to \mathbb {R}$ be *analytic* functions. Suppose $f_k $ converges uniformly to $f $ on $]-\infty,0] $. Is it true that $f_k$ converges to $f$ on $]-\infty, \epsilon [$ for some $\epsilon >0$?

I fail to see a counterexample, but I have never seen this before. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but it seems like you could just take each $f_k$ to be a smooth cutoff function that is $0$ for $x \le 0$ and positive for $x > 0$, and take $f \equiv 0$, so the claim wouldn't hold.

Comment: The functions are analytic (holomorphic) so they can't be like that.

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks.

Comment: $\sum_{n=2}^N \frac{n^{-1+x+i}}{\ln^2 n}$ converges uniformly to the analytic continuation of $F(x) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n^{-1+x+i}}{\ln^2 n}$ on $(-\infty,0]$ but not on a larger interval, and $F''(x) = \zeta(x+i)-1$ which is analytic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f\equiv 0,$ and

$$f_n(x) = \frac{1}{(1+(x-1/n)^2)^{n^3}}, \,\,n=1,2,\dots$$

Then $f_n\to 0$ uniformly on $(-\infty,0].$ That's because $f_n(0)\to 0$ and $f_n(0)=\sup _{(-\infty,0]}f_n.$

But note $f_n(1/n)=1$ for all $n,$ which implies uniform convergence to $0$ fails on $(-\infty,\epsilon)$ for every $\epsilon >0.$

Comment: Yes, this was also my question. The problem here is that the limit function $f $ is not analytic after $0$.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't seen that the limit function is to be analytic. I've changed my answer, and this time I don't have to steal someone else's answer.

Comment: Thank you, great answer !

Comment: You're welcome, thanks.